# How to accept an edit on my own question

Tags: support

Suppose someone suggested an edit to my own question which I approve (and am grateful). Is there any mechanism that allows me to accept the edit straight away that works for users <2k reputation?

Comment: I had that happen once, and I just clicked "accept" and there it was! (unless I misunderstood you?)

Comment: The OP can always directly accept edits to their own question, as far as I can tell. You just have to reach it before two others do.

Comment: @Fabby I tried several times to find that magic button "accept". I always ended up hitting the "next" button, which kindly informed me that I have no privileges to review edits (in this context, to my own question).

Comment: I'll change a proverbial comma in one of your posts so that you can have a look.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski If all you get is the next button then that means the edit suggestion has already been handled (look up above the question/answer and you should get a breakdown of what happened). You still get a notification so you can double check.

Answer (score 1):

If you have "missed" the accept button, it must have been a mistake, [since](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/270345):

> #### Who can vote on a suggested edit?
>
> - The owner of a post may cast a binding vote to accept or reject any modification of their post.